# Broken package system using Ubuntu 18.04 after running software updater

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, update-manager

Broken package system using Ubuntu 18.04 after running software updater

I ran software updater from the gui and this error popped I don't have any ppa's or repositories  enabled

How can I fix this?

[image: error]

I also ran

> sudo apt --fix-broken install

```
useoh@s12s72:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm10 libllvm10:i386 linux-gcp-5.3-tools-5.3.0-1026 linux-gcp-5.3-tools-5.3.0-1029
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.15.0-111-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.15.0 | linux-source-4.15.0 linux-headers-4.15.0-111-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.15.0-111-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,008 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,411 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 972697 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.15.0-111-generic_4.15.0-111.112_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.15.0-111-generic (4.15.0-111.112) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.15.0-111-generic_4.15.0-111.112_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.15.0-111-generic_4.15.0-111.112_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right there in your output: A corrupt package.

```
    Unpacking linux-image-4.15.0-111-generic (4.15.0-111.112) ...
    dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
```

1. Delete the corrupt package from your archive:

   ```
   sudo apt clean linux-image-4.15.0-111-generic
   ```
2. Re-download the correct package:

   ```
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know I had to use the "clean" command